# ActionScript 3 - MovieClip Scale, set to 1 when scale is less than 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a MovieClip of an image and I have applied a TransformGestureEvent to it and its working well, I am just having issues when trying to scale less than 1. I dont want the scale less than 1 so I put a condition in my TransformGestureEvent so when someone tries to scale less than 1 the scale gets reset to 1...I hope this makes sense.

Here is the snippet of code that is giving me trouble.

```
if(event.scaleY < 1.1 && floorplanMC.scaleY < 1){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }
```

and here is the full method:

```
function zoomFloorplan (event:TransformGestureEvent):void{

    myTimerModel.stop();
    myTimerModel.reset();
    myTimerModel.start();

    var locX:Number=event.localX;
    var locY:Number=event.localY;
    var stX:Number=event.stageX;
    var stY:Number=event.stageY;
    var prevScaleX:Number=floorplanMC.scaleX;
    var prevScaleY:Number=floorplanMC.scaleY;
    var mat:Matrix;
    var externalPoint=new Point(stX,stY);
    var internalPoint=new Point(locX,locY);

    floorplanMC.scaleX *= event.scaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY *= event.scaleY;

    if(event.scaleX > 1 && floorplanMC.scaleX > 6){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }

    if(event.scaleY > 1 && floorplanMC.scaleY > 6){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }

    if(event.scaleX < 1.1 && floorplanMC.scaleX < 1){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }

    if(event.scaleY < 1.1 && floorplanMC.scaleY < 1){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }
    mat=floorplanMC.transform.matrix.clone();
    MatrixTransformer.matchInternalPointWithExternal(mat,internalPoint,externalPoint);
    floorplanMC.transform.matrix=mat;
}
```

I dont get any errors, but what I am expecting is if I try to scale less than 1, then the scale of floorplanMC is 1 and MovieClip goes back to the scale it originally was. Currently it doesn't go back to what is was originally, the scale goes less than 1.

Comment: whats the exact error?

Comment: Oh I guess I didn't put what I was expecting vs what is happening...updating now.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: All those if statements should probably be at the bottom, after you do `floorPlanMC.transform.matrix`.  Also, you probably should just look at the floorPlanMC scale in those if statements, instead of the event's scale.

Comment: I see, ill give it a try......by the way would you happen to know how to trigger this event in Adobe Flash Player? I no longer have access to touchscreen.

Comment: You can use the emulator if you have Animate CC.

Comment: I do!!!!!! Thanks again.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I still having trouble triggering the TransformGestureEvent in emulator, I cant find anything when I google it.

Comment: In Animate CC, make sure your project is a Mobile AIR one,  then go to `control -> Test Movie -> In Air Debug Launcher (Mobile)`.   That will bring up  the *simulator* window/panel.  On that, go to the **TOUCH AND GESTURE** section,  check the touch layer checkbox,   select `zoom`,  follow the instructions that come up.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again.